# Having issues with a for loop in Java

Tags: java

I'm checking to see if a given value is present inside an array using a for loop, the problem is that it's jumping directly on the else branch and printing the to be checked value as well(even if the condition is not met). By removing the break; it iterates through the if statement only once and prints the if statement println() and then 6 times the else statement println(). Why is this happening?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   checkArray(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 4);
}

public static void checkArray(int[] q, int a){

   for(int i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
       if(a == q[i]){
           System.out.println("Number " + a + " is indeed present!");
       } else {
           System.out.println("Number " + a + " is not present!");
       }
       break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Add a `return` after printing the found message. And move the not found message to after the loop - you only want to print that after the entire array has been checked..

Comment: because the answer is already closed:
code like this really looks better without for loops. have a look into Streams (Java >= V8)

boolean matched = Arrays.stream(q).anyMatch(elem -> elem == a);
is all you need to print your message with....

Comment: True, but that's for more advanced and experienced developers Stefan, I'm just barely a pup here... =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code exits the loop after the first iteration. Try moving your break inside the `if` block, if you want the loop to exit after the value has been found.

The thing is that, you can say that the number is not in the array only after you have looked till the end. So you should move your `"Not found"` `println()` after the loop, ie after the search reaches the end of the array. Now, I'm not gonna just provide the code, as SO is not a homework website. But do look up linear search on google or ddg.

Comment: It's not really my homework... I'm just practically learning Java from scratch on my own! There's no pressure here, my head will not get cut off if I fail... =)

Comment: Good advice regarding the linear search though! It's a more advanced concept, I like it! Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return` after printing the found message. And move the not found message to after the loop - you only want to print that after the entire array has been checked.

```
public static void checkArray(int[] q, int a)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
       if (a == q[i]) {
           System.out.println("Number " + a + " is indeed present!");
           return;  // Immediately exit the function
       }
    }
    // It will only get here if a is not in the array.
    System.out.println("Number " + a + " is not present!");
}
```

Comment: Sorry Johnny, not working either! It still prints out the last line 3 times and only once the if statement line...

Comment: @Dragos It works: https://ideone.com/mb2nx9. Are you sure you have recompiled and are running the correct code?

Comment: Yes I have made the changes and recompiled, same result! It should print only once  when something is found and only once if the value is not found, but it's not happening... printing  multiple times on my NetBeans 8.1 console.

Comment: @Dragos Then you must not have copied the code correctly. This code absolutely works.

Comment: @Dragos Are you sure you have the last print statement *outside* the `for` statement. Your result indicates that you have it *inside*, after the `if` statement.

Comment: You are right Roger! That was the problem... =D Lack of attention on my behalf! Thank you! =)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will exit the `for` loop at the first iteration, as you put `break` at the end of it. `break` basically exits any loop, so you just need to remove that, and it will work!

It is usually placed in a condition, like an `if` statement. So

```
if (something --> true) {
   run code...
   break (exits the loop).
}
```

Comment: Not functioning Enrico, now I'm getting as follows:                                                   
                                                                                                                                  
run:
Number 4 is not present!
Number 4 is not present!
Number 4 is not present!
Number 4 is indeed present!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to wrong placement of `break` keywork.

You can try with the following function.

```
public static void checkArray(int[] q, int a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
      if (a == q[i]) {
        System.out.println("Number " + a + " is indeed present!");
        break;
      } else {
        System.out.println("Number " + a + " is not present!");
      }
    }
  }
```

Note: put `break` once the condition is satisfied.

A slightly better approach will be like this.

```
public static void checkArray(int[] q, int a) {
      boolean checkFlag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
      if (a == q[i]) {
        checkFlag = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (checkFlag) System.out.println("Number " + a + " is indeed present!");
    else System.out.println("Number " + a + " is not present!");
  }
```

Comment: your first approach is wrong. it would state "Number is not present!" until it finds it e,g, at the end of the list where it would say that it is actualy present. 
Your second aproach indead is better...

Comment: Yes, I agree, it will print as not present several times. This is as per OPs code.

Comment: agreed... but then its wrong there also. ;)

Comment: No Stefan... his second method works just fine! Adding a bool is not a bad idea...

Comment: that is EXACTLY what i wrote. the second one works. the first one not. ;)